# Visualizing $E:=\{a+b\omega\ | a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: number-theory

Given $E:=\{a+b\omega\ | a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ where $\omega$ is a third roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}^*$. Why is it that they form the lattices of equilateral triangles in the plane?

Can you show a pictorial explanation?

Comment: Try to draw $\{a+bi: a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ first.

Comment: The numbers $1,\omega+1,\omega,-1,-\omega-1=\omega^2$ and $-\omega$ are the equally spaced six points on the unit complex circle. In counterclockwise order (with the choice $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$). They are all in the lattice.

Comment: The edge lines of the lattice are *not* part of $E$. The set $E$ is just the vertices. If you want to insert triangle edges, that's fine but it is not part of $E$.

Comment: Sorry, What happens if we have $\omega$ being nth roots of unity instead? DO we get vertexes of n regular polygon? Because I'm not very good with the concepts yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the lattice generated by $1,\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a non-real complex number, has as a base parallelogram, $0,1,\alpha,\alpha+1.$

When $|\alpha|=1$, all sides of the base parallelogram are of length $1$.

When $\omega\neq 1$ is a cube root of $1,$ then it turns out that $\omega+1$ is a sixth root of $1.$ In particular, it means one diagonal of the parallelogram is of length $|1+w-0|=1,$ which means we can cut the base parallelogram into two equilateral triangles by cutting along that diagonal.